# Auto gold price [PHP/MYSQL]

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add gold price in MySQL which is in real time i dont know how to add that int or float in MySQL so i think to add on site which will be auto update every 1 min and write price of the gold in MySQL..But i dont know how to take price of the gold from any site . I think to take price of the gold from this site:http://www.goldpriceoz.com/gold-price-per-gram/ but i dont know how..

I tried this but this isnt working very well..

```
<!-- Begin Gold Price Script - GOLDPRICE.ORG -->
<div style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 210px; height: auto; font-family: Arial; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
<div style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; height: 24px; text-align: center; padding-top: 0px; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; background-color: #000000;">
<a style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" href="http://goldprice.org" target="_blank">Gold Price</a></div>
<div id="gold-price" data-gold_price="USD-o-1d"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://charts.goldprice.org/gold-price.js"></script></div>
<!-- End Gold Price Script - GOLDPRICE.ORG -->


<?php
$html = str_get_html("<div> id="gold-price" </div>");
$price = $html->find('div[id=gold-price]', 0)->innertext;
echo $price;
?>
```

Comment: there's no mysql here which makes this question unclear/too broad.

Comment: 1. get the gold price. 2. Extract it. 3. Write it to mysql using PDO or similar. 4. Setup cronjob that runs each minute.

Comment: Good idea: Find a feed API (Google, Yahoo YQL) to get the current market price. Find out the data limits since once a minute could be frowned upon. Bad idea: scrape it from a site. Definitely frowned upon, and could get you blocked. Especially if you do it every minute.

Comment: curl is your friend. learn how to use it in PHP.

Comment: I know this code which i am write here in PHP does not have any sense but i must something to write to post here this is my first post on stackoverflow.com i only in all this dont know how to take price and set it as PHP Variable...